# Multiple associations with rails Audited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-audited

I am using the Audited gem for Rails, and am using the associated audits like so:

```
audited allow_mass_assignment: true, associated_with: :protocol
```

The problem is, I need this particular model's audits to be associated with more than one models. I was hoping that something like this will work:

```
audited allow_mass_assignment: true, associated_with: [:protocol, :patient]
```

But it doesn't.
It provides a clear error stating:

```
[:protocol, :patient] is not a symbol nor a string
```

The only [related page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/audited/cwc2s43stdM) I could find claims it is simply not possible, but it is quite old and I hope there is some workaround.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested it but try it on seperate lines, like:

```
audited allow_mass_assignment: true, associated_with: :protocol
audited allow_mass_assignment: true, associated_with: :patient
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching if you can use `associated_with` with multiple associations, currently [that is not possible](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/337).

Although, someone submitted a [PR](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/pull/342), it did not work as expected.